# Какое сочетание цветов более удобно?

Tags: html, текст, веб-дизайн

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>
     Космоинфо
    </title>
    <body>
        <style>
         h1{text-align:center;color:white;}
            h3{text-align:center;color:white;}
            h2{color:teal;}
            body{background-image:url("https://novostivmire.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81.jpg");}
        </style>
        </style>
     <h1>Космоинфо</h1>
        <h3>Погрузись в космос вместе с нами!</h3>
        <h1><pre>Новости   Вопросы   Основная   Статьи   Астрофото   Видео</pre></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Здравствуйте. Я разрабатываю сайт. Помимо верстки, программирования мне еще приходится самому разрабатывать дизайн сайта. Вот разрабатываю дизайн главной страницы. HTML-код ее выше.

Проблема в том, что фон страницы темный, а надписи получается, должны быть светлыми. 
Я хочу совет: какого цвета лучше должны быть крупные(последний  с ) заголовки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Более удобно подбирать палитру для сайта с помощью бесплатных сервисов:

1. http://www.rehabcenter.marketing/tintui/index.html
2. https://coolors.co/browser/latest/1 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. [adobe](https://color.adobe.com/ru/create/color-wheel/?base=2&rule=Complementary&selected=0&name=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%20Color&mode=rgb&rgbvalues=0.7,0,0,1,0.09999999999999998,0.09999999999999998,1,0,0,0,0.7,0.19811320754715778,0,1,0.28301886792451114&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4)
4. http://colorhunt.co/ 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос не очень то и ясен... но во всяком случае может быть вам стоит почитать 
[эту](https://habrahabr.ru/post/105250/) и [эту](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ua-hosting/blog/275919/) статью..